# PRITUNL - Error after setup-key (No web access)

Tags: 16.04, openvpn

I'm having trouble when trying to install Pritunl on Ubuntu server 16.04.

After installing all the packages as explained in the documentation I'm having trouble when I have to enter the setup key.

I already checked mongodb and it's working as expected.

Right after that I have no web access and the pritunl service is down as you can see:

```
[undefined][2018-01-04 22:19:13,742][INFO] Stopping server
[undefined][2018-01-04 22:22:40,208][ERROR] Pritunl setup failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pritunl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pritunl/setup/__init__.py", line 41, in setup_all
    setup_host()
  File "/usr/lib/pritunl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pritunl/setup/host.py", line 21, in setup_host
    host.init()
  File "/usr/lib/pritunl/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pritunl/host/utils.py", line 112, in init
    settings.local.host.load()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'load'
[undefined][2018-01-04 22:22:40,210][INFO] Stopping server
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Same problem with Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64, Debian 8.9 x64 and Debian 9.3 x64

Comment: Hi ! You shoud do an update as they release a new version a few hours ago

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version who seems to fix the inital setup bug. I'm going to update and tell you about the results.

[pritunel new release v1.28.1578.26](https://github.com/pritunl/pritunl/releases/tag/1.28.1578.26)

Comment: Yup ! All good now with the update. Now i Have to found a way to use Let's Encrypt with pritunl